# Интроспекция в C++ средствами Python'а

Tags: c++, python, рефлексия

Собственно, в заголовке вся суть вопроса, но опишу подробнее, что меня заинтересовало: python предоставляет нам [API](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/index.html) для C/C++ - должен признаться, что на данный момент я видел только примеры расширений *для python'а* написанные на C++ - возможно ли задействовать этот механизм в "обратную сторону"? Конкретно - можно ли для уже *существующих* (это важный момент) классов в C++ создать что-то вроде "оберток" на python'е, к которым мы могли бы применить нативные для python'а техники интроспекции? 

[Раздел API](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/reflection.html), касающийся рефлексии, посмотрел, но ничего полезного по данному вопросу оттуда для себя не подчерпнул.

---

Если это в принципе технически невозможно сделать - то прошу объяснить, почему.

---

P.S. Только пожалуйста, не Boost'ую реализацию - хотелось бы понять весь механизм от начала до конца, или хотя бы на словах - общий ход действий.

Comment: Поскольку с рефлексией в плюсах туго, придется использовать какие-то препроцессоры, которые предоставят необходимую информацию для python стороны.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, ну, почему же, вот *mirror*, например :) Не буду обманывать, код смотрел не долго - но вот документ, который появился изначально, почитал, - это жесть. По делу: я как-рази таки думал избавиться от любой метаинформации.

Comment: Вы хотите сгенерировать Python обёртку из C++ кода, а затем использовать  средства Питона, чтобы узнать что-то о C++ коде? (окольным путём) Посмотрите [как cppyy работает](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/cppyy.html).

Comment: @jfs, абсолютно верно. Спасибо Вам, сейчас посмотрю.